# Not set ajax response in select box

Tags: jquery, ajax

My ajax function is like this I'm getting data in response, but can not set response data in select box:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myarray;

    function getmember() {
        myarray = [];
        myarray.push($(".group_id").val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getmember.php",
            data: 'group_id=' + myarray.join(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('.groop').append(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    </script>
</head>
```

My html is like this:

```
<select>
    <option>Select User</option>
    <div class="groop"></div>
</select>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - the `div` cannot go inside a `select`.

Comment: Than How should i put my div @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Anywhere outside of the `select`

Comment: How `data` looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your response is `option` HTML.

You should append the data to `select`:

```
var myarray;

function getmember() {
    myarray = [];
    myarray.push($(".group_id").val());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getmember.php",
        data: 'group_id=' + myarray.join(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#mySelect').append('<option value="' + data + '">'+ data + '</option>');
            // ^^^^^^
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Select User</option>
    <div class="groop"></div>
</select>
```

Comment: `Assuming your response is option HTML.` Inspect your `select`

Comment: in my response i am just getting data

Comment: What `data`? as string `data`?

Comment: it's overwrite value in my another select box

Comment: @Prashant Add `id` to your `select` and use that

Comment: me done it already but value not came in select box it's print all value in screen

Comment: with this it is give me all value in in one line

Answer (score 0):

JQuery :

```
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myarray;

    function getmember() {
        myarray = [];
        myarray.push($(".group_id").val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getmember.php",
            data: 'group_id=' + myarray.join(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('.groop').append(data);
                $(".groop").html('');

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $(".groop").append('<option value=' + data[i].YourId + '>' + data[i].YourText + '</option>');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    </script>
</head>
```

HTML :

```
<select id="ddlYourName" class="groop" onchange="getmember()"></select>
```

Comment: in select box value are undefined